# Is there a way to Output 'Extent Report Results' to a Unique Directory?

Tags: junit, cucumber, extent

Is there a way to Output 'Extent Report Results' to a Unique Directory?

For example lets say i execute the my Cucumber framework for the first time > a output folder will be created with the relevant html report as listed:
[image]

But is there a way to output a unique folder of the unique report captured at the time of execution, something in the lines of:

[image]

I have the following Extent config:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<extentreports>
    <configuration>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <documentTitle>Cucumber Extent Reports - v3.0.5</documentTitle>
        <reportName>Automation Framework Cucumber Report</reportName>
        <reportHeadline> - v3.0.5</reportHeadline>
    </configuration>
</extentreports>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the appropriate constructor of `ExtentHtmlReporter`...

```
ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(OUTPUT_FOLDER + FILE_NAME);
```

Set up folder name to whatever you desire.

Comment: thanks, if i was to apply this code based on Test Failure (Screenshot capture based on failure) would i then be able to align the images based upon the test which has failed within the html report?